# Multi processing Python script not pooling

Tags: python, arrays, python-multiprocessing, pool

I'll start with a caveat, I'm still reasonably new to Python and have done a lot of self teaching so apologies if there's something obvious or silly I've done / not done.  The reference to the file name in the code below has been removed but that bit works fine.  I've also stripped back the calculations just so you can get a flavour of what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a text file containing rows of both numeric and string fields that takes the form
`0,0,0,a,b,c,d` which I import into an array and append other columns that I use during calculations.

I need to cycle through each of the lines in this array and assess it against every other line which is expensive from a computation and memory perspective.  Once the assessment against each line is made I then need to overwrite data in the array for both lines.

My plan is to use a multiprocessing pool and array to cycle through the data as quickly as possible whilst each process works on the same copy of the array.  This means there are times where several processes could be attempting to write to the same row.

I've created the code below but my issue is that the code runs, doesn't through up any error messages but doesn't "jump" into the ComputeResult function as it doesn't print the "Computing result for..." line or stop when I put a breakpoint in that function.  Why is this the case?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def AnalysisSettingsFunction(FileNumber):

    FilesList = []
    FilesList.append(r"\\...File to import.txt")

    if FileNumber != -1 :
        ImportFile = (FilesList[FileNumber])
    else:
        ImportFile = len(FilesList)

    OtherVariable = 21
    
    return ImportFile, OtherVariable

def ComputeResult(Args):

    ProcessLock, FileNumber, DataSet, RowNumber, LineCount = Args
    
    print(f"Computing result for {RowNumber}", flush=True)

    for C in range(RowNumber+1, LineCount):
        
        RowData = DataSet[RowNumber]
        OtherRow = DataSet[C]

        Value1 = RowData[0]
        Value2 = RowData[1]
        Value3 = OtherRow[0]
        Value4 = OtherRow[1]

        with ProcessLock:
            
            if Value1 > Value3:
                RowData[12] = Value1 * Value2
                OtherRow[12] = Value1 * Value2
            else:
                RowData[12] = Value3 * Value4
                OtherRow[12] = Value3 * Value4

def main(FileNumber):
    
    AnalysisSettings = AnalysisSettingsFunction(FileNumber)
    FileToImport = AnalysisSettings[0]

    #Importing data into array
    RawDataSet = []
    with open(FileToImport) as f:
        for line in f:
            StrippedLine = line.rstrip() + ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1000000,0,1000000,0,100,-100,0,100,-100,0,0,0,0,0"    
            RawDataSet.append(StrippedLine.split(",",))

    LineCount = len(RawDataSet)

    ProcessLock = mp.Lock()
    DataSet = mp.Array(c_wchar_p, np.array(RawDataSet, dtype=str).flatten(), lock=ProcessLock)
    del RawDataSet

    with mp.Pool() as Pool:
        Args = [(ProcessLock, FileNumber, DataSet, i, LineCount) for i in range(LineCount)]
        Pool.starmap_async(ComputeResult, Args)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Script Started")
    AnalysisSettings = AnalysisSettingsFunction(-1)
    NumberofFiles = AnalysisSettings[0]

    for FileNumber in range(NumberofFiles):
        AnalysisSettings = AnalysisSettingsFunction(FileNumber)
        main(FileNumber)
    
    print("Script Finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `starmap_async` but you do not wait for it to execute.  This method returns an AsyncResult object (this is not clear from the documentation, unfortunately).  Unless you call wait() or get() on the AsyncResult object, the main Process will not wait for the worker Process to finish computing the result.  Since you immediately exit from the with Pool context, the Pool may be closed before the subprocess does anything.

Your ComputeResult method doesn't return anything, so you might as well just call wait() on the returned object. Like this:

```
with mp.Pool() as Pool:
    Args = [(ProcessLock, FileNumber, DataSet, i, LineCount) for i in range(LineCount)]
    Pool.starmap_async(ComputeResult, Args).wait()
```

I think ComputeResult(Args) should be declared as ComputeResult(*Args) to be consistent with the rest of your code, but I didn't check this.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for responding.  What you say makes sense and I've added the .wait() but nothing happens.  ComputeResult doesn't return anything but (as far as I understand) it shouldn't need to as it's working on the DataSet mp.array object which after adding the wait still isn't being updated.

Comment: Python Processes do not share memory.  When you pass a list of objects to ComputeResult, Python makes a copy (using the pickle module) of the list, transmits to the secondary process using a mp.Pipe (or a mp.Queue), and recreates it in the secondary Process (unpickling).  When you modify this object you aren't changing the original list or its items.  That's why your original object doesn't change.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that.  How would I go about using the shared memory so that each of the processes altered a single copy of the list?  The files I need to import can be massive and take huge chunks of memory so copying the list to each process needs to be avoided.